# : arguments must be process or job IDs

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I want to run a simple bash script (referred as killprocess.sh below) to kill a particular process/service running in particular port (say 8080) in a remote machine where both are having OS Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I established a connection via ssh (openssh) as follows to execute the script. Connection is established successfully too.

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -n user@172.16.20.70 -f "/bin/bash /home/killprocess.sh"
```

The contents of killprocess.sh is given below.

```
processID=$(lsof -t -i:8080)
echo $processID
kill $processID
```

Though it correctly print the process ID on the console it gives an error message below that implies it is not possible to kill it.

> : arguments must be process or job IDs

Comment: Try to run the script with -x option. That way you will see what exactly is executing in the `kill $processID` line  `


sshpass -p "password" ssh -n user@172.16.20.70 -f "/bin/bash -x /home/killprocess.sh" `

Comment: thanks. Using this I was able to find the error which is, it is grabbed as _processID=$(lsof -t -i:8080)\r_

Answer (score 2):

Run the `fromdos killprocess.sh` command to make your script work (it is included in the `tofrodos` package).

Here is why.

The error message suggests that you've written your script in a Windows text editor, which handles the line endings differently (adding `\r\n` to the end of the line instead of just `\n`). The error message is suspect because it should be something like

```
bash: kill: meh: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

It would output a line like you've mentioned only if the argument of the `kill` command contained a `\r` (carriage return) character. So when the error message is printed, before the third colon, the cursor jumps back to the beginning of the line, and the rest of the error message overwrites anything which was printed so far. This also explains why the `kill` command complained: it received something like `1234\r`, which cannot be a process ID.

Most probably this is because the first line of your script is actually

```
processID=$(lsof -t -i:8080)\r
```

but you can't see the `\r` character of course, since it's a non-printing one. You can't see it on the output of the second line, since it outputs the line, the cursor jumps back to the beginning, but then the newline character causes the cursor to go to the next line.

By the way, the unix/windows line ending problem is always suspected if a bash error message begins with a colon.

Comment: Cool, I was only aware of the similar utility `dos2unix` and `fromdos` is new to me.

Comment: when I say fromdos, it gives me an error _bash: fromdos: command not found_

Comment: I am using notepad++ as the editor and thus is the problem _processID=$(lsof -t -i:8080)\r_ as you mentioned

Comment: The `fromdos` command is included in the `tofrodos` package. I've modified my post to include this as well. Sorry, it just slipped my mind the first time.